# BiqQuery: querying a view without permissions to query underlying tables

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a table which requires a drive access scope to be queried. I was wondering if there is a way to create a view which wouldn't require this permission to be queried.

Comment: AFAIK, no, it's not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible as per documentation about [data drive access](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-drive#required_permissions)
You will need access to data drive.

But as a workaround you can move that data into a dataset on bigquery that will work like an [authorized view](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authorized-views). As per definition:

> Giving a view access to a dataset is also known as creating an authorized view in BigQuery. An authorized view lets you share query results with particular users and groups without giving them access to the underlying tables. You can also use the view's SQL query to restrict the columns (fields) the users are able to query.

Still, your users will need have access to the dataset that stores the view.

> For your data analysts to query the view, they need to be granted the bigquery.dataViewer role on the dataset containing the view.

On that way it would be possible to query data which have access restrictions. Even on google documentation there is a guide you can use to produce such query named [Create an authorized view](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/share-access-views).